# Android: Require a image to be saved temporarily

Tags: android, image, caching, storage

I have a scenario which I am not sure which type of storage to use. I have a viewpager where each pages required to save a bitmap in local device which user have drawn on the page. If I used application cache, the file in the cache will get deleted if low. If that happened, the user swiped to previous screen will be gone at some point.

If I used application directory itself, I have to manually remove all the files in that directory.

Is the second option a way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the application directory and on your activity/fragment destruction event where you have your `ViewPager`, , you can write the code to delete those files.

Answer (score 0):

Use Picasso library which will manage images caching automatically,

It will restore the deleted image from the disk into the memory again when you slide back to the previous page , so you don't have to save the images on the application directory.

http://square.github.io/picasso/